# What software exists for learning the English language in Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation, language-support, education

I'm searching for software to learn and improve in the English language. But i can't find the proper software.

Specifically, I'm looking for vocabulary software to improve my word range, like software for:

- 504 absolutely essential words
- 1100 words

or other words book.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Anki](http://ankisrs.net/) is a great software for learning all kinds of stuff. There also is an Android version, so you can learn your stuff when you're waiting somewhere but still type in or choose from [premade decks](https://ankiweb.net/shared/decks/) what you want to learn on your computer because it has a sync feature.

Answer (score 3):

Anki is my favorite, and I use it every day, but Duolingo is also a great resource that I use pretty often too. While Anki has a .deb install package Duolingo is just a website, but also has ios and android apps.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use dictionary.com? It has great "word of the day" features. And it's platform independent. Same goes for merriam-webster.com and other online dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [duolingo](https://de.duolingo.com/). 
It is browser based and independent from operating system.